# jQuery datepicker: style certain dates differently

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using a jQuery datepicker combined with the isotope plugin filter feature to filter out divs dependant on dates. The `.blocks` divs each have dates assigned via `data-value` allowing you to filter the divs out. e.g. the first instance of `.blocks` has 3 dates `1782013 1882013 1982013`. I'm looking to style these dates separately, i.e. every instance of a date in the `data-value` attribute, I would like to be assigned a separate class in the `#datepicker` so they can be styled differently. 
jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/neal_fletcher/9WnYY/ 
HTML:

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
<div id="block-wrap">
    <div class="blocks" data-value="1782013 1882013 1982013">17/08 — 19/08</div>
    <div class="blocks" data-value="2182013 2282013 2382013">21/08 — 23/08</div>
    <div class="blocks" data-value="2582013 2682013 2782013 2882013 2982013">25/08 — 29/08</div>    
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var $container = $('#block-wrap');
var $blocks = $("div.blocks", "#block-wrap");

$(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        //nextText: '&rarr;',
        //prevText: '&larr;',
        showOtherMonths: true,
        //dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
        dayNamesMin: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
        //showOn: "button",
        //buttonImage: "img/calendar-blue.png",
        //buttonImageOnly: true,
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            var date = new Date(dateText);
            var dateValue = date.getDate().toString() + (date.getMonth() + 1).toString() + date.getFullYear().toString();

            $container.isotope({
                filter: '[data-value~="' + dateValue + '"]'
            });
        }
    });
});

$container.imagesLoaded(function () {
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.blocks',
        animationEngine: 'css',
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: 5
        }
    });
});

var prepareData = function (howLong) {
    var mode = howLong,
        date = new Date(),
        days = 0,
        d = date.getDate(),
        m = date.getMonth(),
        y = date.getFullYear(),
        duration = [],
        durationReady = [];

    if (mode === "week") {
        days = 7;
    } else if (mode === "month") {
        days = 30;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < days; i++) {
        // for each day create date objects in an array
        duration[i] = new Date(y, m, d + i);

        // convert objects into strings
        // fe. 25th of May becomes '2552013'
        durationReady[i] = duration[i].getDate().toString() + (duration[i].getMonth() + 1).toString() + duration[i].getFullYear().toString();

        // 1. select all items which contain given date
        var $applyMarkers = $('.blocks[data-value~="' + durationReady[i] + '"]')
            .each(function (index, element) {
            var thisElem = $(element),
                thisElemAttr = thisElem.attr('data-value');
            // 2. for each item which does not contain a marker yet, apply one    
            if (thisElemAttr.indexOf(mode.substring(0, 1)) === -1) {
                thisElem.attr('data-value', (thisElemAttr += ' ' + mode));
            }
        });
    }
};

prepareData("week");
prepareData("month");

$("#today").on("click", function () {
    var date = new Date();
    var dateValue = date.getDate().toString() + (date.getMonth() + 1).toString() + date.getFullYear().toString();

    $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', date);

    $container.isotope({
        filter: '[data-value~="' + dateValue + '"]'
    });
});


$("#week").on("click", function () {
    $container.isotope({
        filter: '[data-value ~="week"]'
    });
});

$("#month").on("click", function () {
    $container.isotope({
        filter: '[data-value ~="month"]'
    });
});
```

Is it therefore possible to collect all the dates stored in the `data-value` attributes, store them as a variable and pass them via the `beforeshowday` function to style them separately? If that is at all possible? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is the date `1782013` stands for if it is `17 Aug 2013` your date format is buggy... please make it `17082013` else you will have problem is parsing dates like `01 Aug 2013` as your representation might become `112013`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at the [showBeforeDay](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) option

```
$(function () {
    var blocks = $('#block-wrap .blocks')
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        //nextText: '&rarr;',
        //prevText: '&larr;',
        showOtherMonths: true,
        //dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
        dayNamesMin: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
        //showOn: "button",
        //buttonImage: "img/calendar-blue.png",
        //buttonImageOnly: true,
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            var date = new Date(dateText);
            var dateValue = date.getDate().toString() + (date.getMonth() + 1).toString() + date.getFullYear().toString();

            $container.isotope({
                filter: '[data-value~="' + dateValue + '"]'
            });
        },
        beforeShowDay: function(date){
            var target = $.datepicker.formatDate( 'ddmmyy', date);
            var contains = blocks.filter('[data-value*="' + target + '"]').length > 0;
            return [true, contains ? 'special' : '', '']
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/h6YjW/)

Note: As I said in the comment, I've made a slight change to the `data-value` format, the date format is changed to `ddmmyyyy`

Comment: cheers for your answer, works great, much appreciated! There is one small problem though, changing the date format does break the filter function, i.e. clicking on the `17/08/2013` block filters out all the content as the date format has now changed. Is there any way for both functions to work in unison?